# Can I monitor home network and throttle traffic?

Tags: 10.04, network-manager, network-monitoring

I have several computers in my network and would like to see which computer is hogging too much speed, then possibly throttle that PC. All computers are going through one router, both wired and wireless. I have tried wireshark, but is very complicated and I can't seem to get anything other than usb monitoring, and cacti installed, but doesn't even show up on the menu (At least I can't find it).

Any help appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're using your Ubuntu machine **as** a router, I'm not sure you can influence the connection received by anyone else connected.

That said, most routers will come with a Quality of Service engine (or something similar) which will allow you to priorities network traffic, and may even be able to throttle individual usage. This will depend a on your router though.

Comment: Yeah my router has QoS, but it doesn't seem to work at all. I have set my mac address and IP address to high priority, and son's computer to low, but he can still pull half the data while we both download big files to test. I was afraid i'd have to run my machine as a gateway. thanks though.